# Old record field update

Tags: automation

I have a question regarding field update, Is there any way to copy one field from another related object field for the older records without using Data Loader?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field and a WF rule to update this field based on your logic. Now make Dml in developer console and update all record. So your WF will run and update the field.

Eg: if your object is Account then dml would be

```
Update [ select id from account limit 10000];
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the data correction. If not you can always take use apex coding to make sure new value will be copied to the field in related objects.

Comment: Yeah its like data correction. Created a new field which needs to be updated from the related object field. For new and update it can be done by process builder but what about older records?